# How to get Latex bold greek symbol with matplotlib for a title above a subplot

Tags: math-mode, bold, boldmath, matplotlib, boldsymbol

I have the following subplot (indexed by `m`and `n`given) :

```
ax = g.subplots[m,n]
```

I tried to set in bold Latex all the Latex expression $1 sigma \pm 0.1$.

I have set up at the beginning of matplotlib script :

```
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

I did different attempts with :

```
ax.set_title("$\mathbf{1 \sigma \pm} "+str('0.1')+"$", fontsize=18)

ax.set_title("$\\mathbf{1 \sigma \pm} "+str('0.1')+"$", fontsize=18)

ax.set_title("$\\mathbf{1} \boldsymbol{\sigma} \pm "+str('0.1')+"$", fontsize=18)

ax.set_title("$\\mathbf{1} \\boldsymbol{\sigma} \pm "+str('0.1')+"$", fontsize=18)
```

But none of these solutions works. Any help would be great. Regards

Comment: I've flagged the question as this really has very little to do with LaTeX but more to do with  Python and Matplotlib, and so would be better suited to StackOverflow I suspect.

Comment: It might be a LaTeX question I think, it depends a bit on what actually goes wrong. Do you get an error message or a warning in Python? If so, what is the error? Or do you get output (and no errors or warnings), but not what you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use the LaTeX `bm` package via `rcParams`

You can tell Matplotlib to use LaTeX, and aside from some aesthetic settings (well worth having a look through) you can tell it to do do some stuff with LaTeX, such give it a small preamble, where among other things you can import packages. For bold maths the best package is the `bm` package (as far as I am aware). Hence a MWE is

```
import matplotlib as mpl
rc_fonts = {
    "text.usetex": True,
    'text.latex.preview': True, # Gives correct legend alignment.
    'mathtext.default': 'regular',
    'text.latex.preamble': [r"""\usepackage{bm}"""],
}
mpl.rcParams.update(rc_fonts)
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

plt.clf()
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax = axs[0]
ax.set_title(r'$\bm{1 \sigma \pm 1}$')
```

However, I notice you want to adjust the font size. Again this is best done through `rcParams`, so to demo a more comprehensive `rcParams` configuration which gives the best results I would recommend:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
rc_fonts = {
    "text.usetex": True,
    'text.latex.preview': True,
    "font.size": 20,
    'axes.titlesize': 22,
    "axes.labelsize": 22,
    "legend.fontsize": 20,
    "xtick.labelsize": 20,
    "ytick.labelsize": 20,
    'figure.titlesize': 22,
    'mathtext.default': 'regular',
    'text.latex.preamble': [r"""\usepackage{bm}"""],
}
mpl.rcParams.update(rc_fonts)
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

plt.clf()
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax = axs[0]
ax.set_title(r'$\bm{1 \sigma \pm 1}$')
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ! Regards